# Is it possible to see the type hierarchy of an annotation in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse, the `CTRL + T` or `F4` key shortcuts exist for seeing the type hierarchy of classes and interfaces. This helps me for example to quickly find the implementing classes for an interface.

Is there a way that i can see the "implementations" of annotations (i.e. all the places that it's being used at)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double-click the annotation and right-click, then choose `References -> Project` from the context menu

I realize that's not a keyboard shortcut, but I have to think you should be able to define one for that command, if that does what you want it to

Comment: the keyboard shortcut for what you indicated was ctrl+g, one of my favorites actually. i wanted to see if it can be done easier though. anyway, thx :)